# Directive template is shown before it's created

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This problem happens in IE and Firefox, not Chrome.

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bkVttZrmzKV5QwKaYISi?p=preview) I have a directive that has a template containing a div. The div is shown with `ng-show="show"` where the variable `show` is set to false when the directive is initialized in `link.pre`.

I added an alert to stop the process right after the variable `show` is initialized with false, but the template is shown anyways.

Why is the div shown if `ng-show` is set to false? I need the template not to be displayed when it's initialized, only when I set `scope.show=true`.

Template:

```
<div ng-show="show">
  This shouldn't be shown
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.directive('dir1', function() {


    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'AE';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.templateUrl = "template.html";

    directive.link = {};

    directive.link.pre = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.show = false;
      alert(1);
    }

    directive.link.post = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    };

    return directive;

});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine - I don't see anything rendered on your example? When setting the `scope.show` to `true` it shows content. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the solution you're looking for, but you could always replace `ng-show` with `ng-if`.  Then set `scope.show` equal to true in the post block. There's no need to initialize it with a value of false, as it is false by default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "angular" hasn't really compiled your template before it shows it. I tried adding `ng-cloak` but it does not seem to work either, so I guess you could use this workaround:

```
<div ng-show="show" class="ng-hide">
  This shouldn't be shown
</div>
```

This way, you force your directive to be hidden by default. If you add:

```
scope.show = true;
```

after you `alert`, it works.

*Please wait to see if there is a better answer before accepting this one.*